# How to avoid direct ALTER with DB project without check in?

Tags: sql-server, tfs-2015, sql-server-data-tools

I have face one problem with SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) and database project which is manage by TFS.

If some one forgot to check-in db script after ALTER the script [ like alter of store procedure ] then it leads to inconsistent script on DB server and DB project which is under source control (TFS).

Above scenario creating major problem in patch creation.

Can any one suggest me the solution.

I used schema comparer option of SSDT before patch creation which help me to sync DB server script with DB project which directly alter without check in.
But not solve the purpose of version control

Comment: If you have an enforced process that goes, check in code, that code gets built on the server into a dacpac, that dacpac is compared to the db and published - and you always follow this process your problem goes away

Comment: Thanks for comment but how we can restrict direct ALTER from Visual studio where DB project is open or check out which create problem as many developers working on same DB

Comment: @VishalHatiskar Yes, We can write `DDL trigger` for restricting `ALTER` from `SSMS`.

Comment: don't write a ddl trigger. each db has their own private copy of the db to develop on - check in changes that get deployed, if devs keep going onto prod db's remove their permissions - automate the whole process

Comment: Revoke access to developers and grant it only to the machine that publishes the project from dacpac